# Proving there is no smallest positive element of any ordered field F

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, ordered-fields

[image]

I missed lecture so these notes may be incomplete and I'm trying to fill in the blanks. Really not following this proof though (feel like maybe some stuff was said out loud but not written down)

Appreciate help understanding/filling in the blanks

Comment: Do you know the definition of an ordered field? The idea is, if $\varepsilon$ is some purported "smallest positive element", you can always show that, actually, there's a smaller one, namely $\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$. But there are lots of steps omitted here: for instance, the statement $0 < \frac{1}{2} < 1$ needs to be proved from the axioms of an ordered field. (In fact, first of all, why does $\frac{1}{2}$ even exist in your field? It doesn't exist in fields of characteristic $2$, for example.)

Comment: Just to get things straight, where do you get lost?  Are you able to show that $0<\frac{1}{2}<1$?

Comment: For showing $0<\frac{1}{2}<1$, I'm a bit uncertain what more needs to be shown (I guess prove this from the axioms).

Comment: And I was stuck at the last step. If $a$ is less than every element $> 0$, $a = 0$..? How does that help us exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, by the axioms, we have $0<1=1+0<1+1=2$ (run through this step-by-step if needed). Now use some more axioms to obtain $0<\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{1}=1$ (again, step-by-step as necessary).

Now, to prove the theorem, assume the opposite, i.e., assume there is a smallest positive element.  Unraveling what this means, we assume there is some positive element $a$ in $\mathbb F$ (so $a>0$) such that for any positive element $b$ of $\mathbb F$, we have $a\leq b$.  Since $0<\frac{1}{2}<1$, we have $0<\frac{1}{2}a<a$.   But $\frac{1}{2}a$ is positve, so by assumption we have $a\leq\frac{1}{2}a<a$. This is a contradiction (can you see why?), and thus the theorem is true.